# MySQL full text search by relevancy with wildcard

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I need to search products and sort them by relevancy , for that I tried this MySQL query

```
SELECT *, MATCH(`SubProductName`) AGAINST ('+app*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS
relevance FROM `tblsubproducts1` WHERE MATCH(SubProductName) AGAINST 
('+app*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)  ORDER BY relevance DESC
```

That query for example returns : Apple Thunderbolt, Apple TV ... as results. which is right.

But when I try with `'+usb*'` it doesn't return any rows, while the database contains a row with `SubProductName` `USB-C Charge Cable` that I can find by matching against `'+cable*'`

To clarify,I want the search to work with partial words like 'app' for apple which is why I added `*`, but why it doesn't always seem to work is what's confusing me here. Is it the `-` in `USB-C` or ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MyISAM, then the minimum word length for full text indexing is 4.  (This is documented [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len).)

In other words, "usb" is not even in the index.  You need to change this parameter and re-build the index.

Comment: that doesn't matter what the search string is right? it matters only with the index?

Comment: in other words, since it works with "app" for apple , the problem is that "usb" is not indexed not that the search string is usb?

Comment: @vlatkozelka . . . It doesn't match `USB-C` because hyphen is treated as a word delimiter.